# What are black rounded rectangles in iPhone apps called

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uiactionsheet, uiactivityindicatorview

A lot of apps use a little center black rounded rectangle when an action is being called to save something to the network and normally contains a throbber.

What are they called in ios? UIActionSheets?

How do I create one when I want to save something?

Comment: It is `UIActivityIndicatorView`

Comment: You can use https://github.com/Dejal/DejalActivityView

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like MBProgressHUD. You can find it here https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: This is what I want. curious what does HUD stand for?

Comment: @chris, HUD stands for Heads-Up Display.. This is usually to show/notify the users that something has been happening/downloading at the background.

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking for loader?
If yes you can use UIActivityIndicatorView

or If you want to use some third party loader, MBProgressHUD will be a great option.

[image]

[MBProgressHUD download from here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/mbprogresshud)

Answer (score 0):

Try using UIAlert
you can customise it if needed

Answer (score 0):

[enter link description here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/svprogresshud)

to show progress use code:

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithMaskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
```

to stop progress use:

```
[SVProgressHUD dismiss];
```

[image]